# Using unicode characters

Tags: java, ms-access, unicode

I have a problem with unicode. I have a multi-language project. When I enter the data in the local language, in Access the data is stored something like this as " à²…à²®à³à²®" but I want those characters of the local language to be seen at the back end.

Ccould you please suggest how to do this?

I'm using Java, Windows vista, and ms-access.
I had set database encoding using properties class and passed it to `getConnection` method.
Though it's not showing what I want.
using `props.put("charset","utf-8")` I am using edit-plus editor.

Comment: am working in java...ms-access is my database..am using winodws vista..not linux

Comment: Jet is your database, not Access.

Comment: Jet is their *DBMS*, not 'database'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check your data at every step, *not* just by printing it out as a string, but by looking at which unicode characters it consists of. See my [debugging unicode](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/debuggingunicode.html) page, which is written for C# but can be applied anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

What (programming) language you're using is absolutely vital. Of course, without knowing that, you could still check to make sure all computers you're using the project on are using the same encoding. If you're on a bash shell, you can type `echo $LANG` and it should probably give you some kind of UTF-8. Bear in mind that many programs, however, will *not* run in the locale of the shell, but in their own locale (especially C). It's a good idea to know what locale your shell is running, what locale all the programs you use are running, and what that locale means as far as text encoding.

However, that's about as much as I can do without knowing what language your project uses. And, depending on the language, that may be as much as I can help you, but someone else will surely take over for me if we can figure out what language we're working with here.

Comment: am working in java...ms-access is my database..am using winodws vista..not linux

Answer (score 1):

What text editors are you using? make sure they support Unicode (preferably utf8), also set the database encoding to utf8, and if your language has a special notation for unicode string, use it ( for Java, I think all strings are Unicode, but for example python 2.5 and lower need to use `u"...."` ).

Answer (score 1):

Is your database configured correctly to use a unicode encoding? It looks like the text is being converted or interpreted incorrectly as a non-unicode format.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer of Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482466/problem-with-unicode-characters#482500) is a good one. In addition to that, I want to encourage you to check the whole trip from browser to database, because sometimes the problem is in a really awkward place. In my case, the problem was caused by a bug in the [RequestDumperValve in Tomcat](http://www.rolfje.com/2008/07/20/tomcat-utf-8-and-the-requestdumpervalve/).